# Logging with WCF and WebSphere MQ

Tags: wcf, ibm-mq

I have a solution where I have configured a WCF one way service with WebSphereMQ.  The is self hosted within a NT service.  This has all been working well for some years but now our customer upgraded to WebSphere 7.5 and since this we have been getting approx once a day:

**Service host went into fault state**

I have been trying to track down what is causing this. I catch all exceptions within my service code and log.  Nothing there!  I have turned on WCF trace, again nothing there! According to the log svclog, there isn't even a message being processed when the host goes into fault state.  So as a final resort I would like to log what is happening in the WebSphere WCF extensions (XMS)

According to the [IBM help page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030120_.htm) this should be no problem and here is my config.

```
 <sources>
   <source name="IBM.XMS.WCF" 
     switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" 
     propagateActivity="true"
     xmsTraceSpecification="*=all=enabled"
     xmsTraceFilePath="E:\Log\Services\JobServiceSTP\AddIns\"
     xmsTraceFileSize="20000000" 
     xmsTraceFileNumber="20" 
     xmsTraceFormat="basic">
     <listeners>
       <add name="traceListener" 
            type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
  initializeData="E:\Log\Services\JobServiceSTP\AddIns\STPMonitor.svclog" />
     </listeners>
   </source>
 </sources>
```

However when I do this I get the following error:

*System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 
'xmsTraceFileNumber' is not a valid configuration attribute for type 'System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.DiagnosticTraceSource*

Am I misunderstanding the IBM help page in any way or missing something for example in the `<configSections>`?
Is there any better way to track down this sudden service host shutdown?

Comment: You could look for info in the error log of the MQ queue manager too.

Comment: I shall look and see if that contains any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you run an MQ trace on the client-side to figure out what the issue is or give the trace to IBM support.

Comment: I don't think that would help much.  The client is running on a different machine and its function call is one way and will finish way before the server even start processing the message.